# activate xdebug on mamp?

Tags: php, xdebug, mamp

i'm using MAMP and want to activate xdebug.

i've uncomment the following row in php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so"
```

i restarted MAMP and opened a php file containing phpinfo() on the web browser and saw a section named "xdebug". so im sure its installed.

however, the browser doesn´t print out any error messages.

how come?

Comment: no one who got a mac and is running xdebug?

Comment: Not sure from your response whether you've gotten your issue completely resolved; however, I recently wrote a post on how I successfully got a MAMP/Xdebug environment setup. If you are still having issues, check out: http://borloz.com/setting-up-a-php-debugging-environment-with-mamp-and-eclipse-pdt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have displaying errors disabled by default. Try to do:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

before causing error in your script.

Comment: no its enabled. still wont work. a lot of users are having problem with mamp+xdebug. i wonder why. you've got a mac? if yes, how did you do it after installing MAMP?

Comment: oh now it worked. although i've got a line error_reporting E_ALL in php.ini i've got another line display_errors = Off and that disabled everything.